# How to set attr from model field in forms in django

Tags: python, django

How to set specific attribute for html template based on model method return value or just a model field name?

I have already known it's possible to override fields by `__init__` function or widgets like this:

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"name", max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)

        def __str__(self):
                return ("%s" % self.title)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Item

fields = ['title',]

widgets = {
         'title': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
                 'class': 'radioselect',
                 'item_name': 'title name?' # <- i want to have title name here of each not statis string
          }),
}
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({
                  'item_name': '' # <- i want to have title name here of each not statis string
          })
```

however, I want to set specific field name, based on previosly defined fields in model not just a static string like in above-mentioned example. 
If i add `Item` into a database with **title = "Apple"** i want to insert this string into this attribute to have such expected result like this in templates:

```
<input type="radio" class="radioselect" item_name="Apple">
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a ModelForm here, and you don't need dynamic fields. You want a normal Form, containing a single ModelChoiceField which will use a queryset to automatically populate itself with all the choices.

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Item.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'radioselect'})
    )
```